# How can I suppress any bibliography commands a documentclass uses?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, document-classes

Is there any command I can put in my preamble that will suppress any bibliography specific commands/environments a documentclass has?

I want to use the cite package and avoid having to define my bibliography the way the documentclass I'm using wants me to. I have tried `\RequirePackage{cite}` it still won't override the documentclass settings. I have considered trying `\PreventPackageFromLoading` but I'm not sure what I would need to prevent from loading to be able to simply use `\cite{}` and `\bibliography{<mybibfile>}` rather than the method the documentclasss wants me to use.

For more clarity the documentclass is the base `proposal` class,

Comment: Looking quickly at the code, the `proposal` class makes extensive use of `biblatex` functionality which you can't really emulate with the `cite` package. You can't really turn it off without rewriting the class. It's possible that `\PreventPackageFromLoading` would work, but you'd still need to change commands in the class that use the `biblatex` macros. If you really want to do this, then make a copy of the class file and edit out the relevant stuff, but you'll lose functionality along the way.